# SlidingMenu with Google Map fragment lock the gestures detection

Tags: java, android, android-layout, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I'm trying to make cooperate SlidingMenu library (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in a FragmentActivity that displays a custom MapFragment with a Google Map, but that causes the disabling of the horizontal gesture detection.

I can move Map in all directions with gestures that not starting in the horizontal axis, but swipe doesn't sort any effects on Map. This happens even if I disable the SlidingMenu or if I set TOUCHMODE_NONE. It's like SlidingMenu FrameLayout overrides the detection of the Map.

I followed this StackOverflow post: [Sliding menu locks touch event on upper view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895149/sliding-menu-locks-touch-event-on-upper-view), using SlidingFragmentActivity tuned with SherlockActionBar, but it still doesn't work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

on this page teach it to use, not to show the menu when you slide on the map, says this line

```
//menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-sliding-menu-like.html